# PhantomJS exits after syntax error when running unit tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-runner

We are running our Jasmine unit tests using a combination of Karma and PhantomJS on the build server. Running the tests locally on Chrome works fine, the error doesn't occur there (which is a different question). Here's what's happening:

At one point in the execution, the test runs into an "undefined" error and simply stops:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X) ERROR
  TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'dropScope.resize')
  at /Users/nwinkler/workspaces/.../foo.js:250
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X): Executed 654 of 1221 ERROR (14.512 secs / 14.386 secs)
DEBUG [karma]: Run complete, exitting.
DEBUG [launcher]: Disconnecting all browsers
```

Even when running karma with the `--force` flag, it still exits at this point.

Is there a way to have Karma/PhantomJS continue running the tests without stopping at this point? Why can't PhantomJS recover from this error?

I'm not looking for solution for the `undefined` error, that's a different topic - I would just like to understand why PhantomJS and Karma exit at this point and don't continue with the remaining unit tests.

Comment: Waiting for a answer on this one also...

Comment: This happens to my suite also regardless of browser. I am trying to test CKEditor and in our tests we create dummy editors that do cause js errors but when you are trying to assert on some kind of dom change the js errors cause Karma to halt test execution.

Comment: Update: When our suite goes above 800 to 1000+ tests these errors seem to stack up and cause the shutdown. I have found that changing load order in the files array helps to but it prevents us from using globs to include tests. Karma should only fail on asserts not errors.

Comment: Do you use --single-run flag ?

Comment: @Boris it doesn't matter if the flag is single or not in my case

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this code to warn about errors and resume the run (phantomjs)

```
phantom.onError = function(msg, trace) {
  var msgStack = ['PHANTOM ERROR: ' + msg];
  if (trace && trace.length) {
    msgStack.push('TRACE:');
    trace.forEach(function(t) {
      msgStack.push(' -> ' + (t.file || t.sourceURL) + ': ' + t.line + (t.function ? ' (in function ' + t.function +')' : ''));
    });
  }
  console.error(msgStack.join('\n'));
  //phantom.exit(1); // do not stop
};
```

if you are using a page object:

```
page.onError = function(msg, trace) {
  // never display errors
   var msgStack = ['SITE ERROR: ' + msg];
  if (trace && trace.length) {
    msgStack.push('TRACE:');
    trace.forEach(function(t) {
      msgStack.push(' -> ' + (t.file || t.sourceURL) + ': ' + t.line + (t.function ? ' (in function ' + t.function +')' : ''));
    });
  }
  console.error(msgStack.join('\n'));
}
```

Comment: Where do you place this code in your configuration? In the Karma configuration file, or in a custom code file that you include with your tests?

Comment: I put this code right above the the first test in the code file.

Comment: @Eun This code had no effect for me. I tried adding it to the top of my first test, also in the phantom launcher code. No effect. Can you be more specific about where this needs to go. What version of phantom you are using to make this work for you? I can't find the onError function this is supposed to be overriding in phantomjs.js.

Comment: @branchgabriel I am using phantomjs 1.9.8. I am using phantomjs directly not called by another application before. onError was first introduced in 1.5 (http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/handler/on-error.html) (the `page.onError` part is of course if your variable is named `page`)

Comment: @Eun Still doesn't work. If you get half the points good for you. Thanks for trying.